# Lubuntu 16.04 no audio after installing OSS

Tags: sound, lubuntu, 64-bit, pulseaudio, alsa

A few days ago, my system was having audio issues where the sound is too soft/low even at full volume. I discovered I fixed this by installing OSS4. All was right and alright until now, I've found out that there's no audio anymore. No sounds. The volume control has gone. I already installed PulseAudio, pavucontrol, I already removed alsa, but no sound still. When starting a youtube video or video file I can see the volume levels of PulseAudio Volume Control move but there's no sound. I've already checked it's not my headphones and the sound is not muted.

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

OSS is no longer supported by Ubuntu/Canonical. [From the wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound):

`Canonical/Ubuntu has chosen to disable OSS support in their kernels and ignore any bugs filed against OSS4 packages. If you're considering using OSS4, you should probably use another Linux distro like Arch Linux.`

In Lubuntu at the moment, there are problems with Firefox having no sound due to ALSA support being disabled by upstream, so until this is fixed, you would be safe completely removing OSS4 from your system and reinstalling PulseAudio.

Comment: Completely removed OSS4 and reinstalled PulseAudio. Still nothing.